# Get localStorage value on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've searched the internet but I can't seem to find anything that works for me.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Heating System Control</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        strLED1 = "";
        strLED2 = "";
        strText1 = "";
        strText2 = "";
        var LED1_state = 0;
        var LED2_state = 0;
        function GetArduinoIO()
            {
                nocache = "&nocache=" + Math.random() * 1000000;
                var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                request.onreadystatechange = function()
                {
                    if (this.readyState == 4) {
                        if (this.status == 200) {
                            if (this.responseXML != null) 
                            {
                            // XML file received - contains analog values, switch values and LED states
                                document.getElementById("input1").innerHTML =
                                    this.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('analog')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                                document.getElementById("input2").innerHTML =
                                    this.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('analog')[1].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                                // LED 1
                                if (this.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('LED')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue === "on") {
                                    document.getElementById("LED1").innerHTML = "ON";
                                    document.getElementById("LED1").style.backgroundColor = "green";
                                    document.getElementById("LED1").style.color = "white";
                                    LED1_state = 1;
                                }
                                else {
                                    document.getElementById("LED1").innerHTML = "OFF";
                                    document.getElementById("LED1").style.backgroundColor = "red";
                                    document.getElementById("LED1").style.color = "white";
                                    LED1_state = 0;
                                }
                                // LED 2
                                if (this.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('LED')[1].childNodes[0].nodeValue === "on") {
                                    document.getElementById("LED2").innerHTML = "ON";
                                    document.getElementById("LED2").style.backgroundColor = "green";
                                    document.getElementById("LED2").style.color = "white";
                                    LED2_state = 1;
                                }
                                else {
                                    document.getElementById("LED2").innerHTML = "OFF";
                                    document.getElementById("LED2").style.backgroundColor = "red";
                                    document.getElementById("LED2").style.color = "white";
                                    LED2_state = 0;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                // send HTTP GET request with LEDs to switch on/off if any
                request.open("GET", "ajax_inputs" + strLED1 + strLED2 + nocache, true);
                request.send(null);
                setTimeout('GetArduinoIO()', 1000);
                strLED1 = "";
                strLED2 = "";
            }
        function GetButton1()
            {
                if (LED1_state === 1) 
                {
                    LED1_state = 0;
                    strLED1 = "&LED1=0";
                }
                else 
                {
                    LED1_state = 1;
                    strLED1 = "&LED1=1";
                }
            }
        function GetButton2()
            {
                if (LED2_state === 1) 
                {
                    LED2_state = 0;
                    strLED2 = "&LED2=0";
                }
                else 
                {
                    LED2_state = 1;
                    strLED2 = "&LED2=1";
                }
            }
        function SendText1()
            {
                nocache = "&nocache=" + Math.random() * 1000000;
                var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

                strText2 = "&txt2=" + document.getElementById("txt_form1").form_text1.value + "&end2=end";

                request.open("GET", "ajax_inputs" + strText2 + nocache, true);
                request.send(null);
            }
        function SendText2()
            {
                nocache = "&nocache=" + Math.random() * 1000000;
                var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

                strText1 = "&txt1=" + document.getElementById("txt_form2").form_text2.value + "&end1=end";

                request.open("GET", "ajax_inputs" + strText1 + nocache, true);
                request.send(null);
            }
        function clsTxt1()
            {
            setTimeout(
              function clearTxt()
              {
                  document.getElementById("txt_form1").form_text1.value = "";
              }, 500)
            }
        function clsTxt2()
            {
            setTimeout(
              function clearTxt()
              {
                  document.getElementById("txt_form2").form_text2.value = "";
              }, 500)
            }
        function Threshold1()
        {
            var thr1 = document.getElementById("txt_form1").form_text1.value;
            document.getElementById("thresh1").innerHTML = thr1;
        }
        function Threshold2()
            {
                var thr2 = document.getElementById("txt_form2").form_text2.value;
                document.getElementById("thresh2").innerHTML = thr2;
            }
    </script>
    <style>
        .IO_box 
        {
            float: left;
            margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
            border: 1px solid black;
            padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
            width: 100px;
            height: 196px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        h1 
        {
            font-family: Helvetica;
            font-size: 120%;
            color: blue;
            margin: 5px 0 10px 0;
            text-align: center;
        }
        h2 
        {
            font-family: Helvetica;
            font-size: 85%;
            color: black;
            margin: 10px 0 5px 0;
            text-align: center;
        }
        p, form
        {
            font-family: Helvetica;
            font-size: 80%;
            color: #252525;
            text-align: center;
        }
        button
        {
            font-family: Helvetica;
            font-size: 80%;
            max-width: 100px;
            width: 90px;
            height: 25px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            text-align: center;
            border: none;
        }
        input
        {
            font-family: Helvetica;
            font-size: 80%;
            max-width: 100px;
            width: 90px;
            height: 25px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            text-align: center;
            border: none;
        }
        .small_text 
        {
            font-family: Helvetica;
            font-size: 70%;
            color: #737373;
            text-align: center;
        }
        textarea
        {
            resize: none;
            max-width: 90px;
            margin-bottom: 1px;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body onload="GetArduinoIO(); Threshold1()">
        <h1>Heating System Control</h1>
        <div class="IO_box">
            <h2>Room One</h2>
            <p>Temp1 is: <span id="input1">...</span></p>
            <button type="button" id="LED1" onclick="GetButton1()" color="white" backgroundColor="red" style="border: none;">OFF</button><br /><br />
            <form id="txt_form1" name="frmText">
                <textarea name="form_text1" rows="1" cols="10"></textarea>
            </form>
            <input type="submit" value="Set Temp" onclick="SendText1(); clsTxt1(); Threshold1();" style ="background-color:#5F9EA0" />
            <p>Threshold: <span id="thresh1">...</span></p>
        </div>
        <div class="IO_box">
            <h2>Room Two</h2>
            <p>Temp2 is: <span id="input2">...</span></p>
            <button type="button" id="LED2" onclick="GetButton2()" color="white" backgroundColor="red" style="border: none;">OFF</button><br /><br />
            <form id="txt_form2" name="frmText">
                <textarea name="form_text2" rows="1" cols="10"></textarea>
            </form>
            <input type="submit" value="Set Temp" onclick="SendText2(); clsTxt2(); Threshold2();" style ="background-color:#5F9EA0" />
            <p>Threshold: <span id="thresh2">...</span></p>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

So my question is, How can I keep the value inserted in the text area even after I reload the page (from the "Threshold1()" function)? I found a few examples with "localStorage" and JQuery, but I have no idea how to call the saved value when I reload the page.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Stefan.

Comment: `localStorage.getItem()` ? MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage

Comment: How and where do I put it? I need to get the value when the page loads, and print it in the <body> section of the page

Comment: After the user writes something in the text area, you read the value of the text area, and you put it in local storage by saying, for example, `localStorage.setItem('threshold1', valueFromTextArea);`. Then, when the page loads, you can say `var storedValue = localStorage.getItem('threshold1');` and write that value wherever you want. The first argument in `setItem()` can be any string you want, and the second one is the value you want to store. Then, you can pass that string to `getItem()` to retrieve the value you stored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **Local Storage Explained**

The `localStorage` object likes to store strings, so how would one store large objects, let's say some complex data structure? - Simple, JavaScript has a neat function built in, look up  `JSON.stringify(object)`. So all you would need to do is something like below to store some complex object is something like the code I've provided below. Then to retrieve an object from the `localStorage` you'll want to use `JSON.parse(object);`.

To look into `localStorage`, I strongly suggest you take a look at the likes of [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) and if you want to look into the `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify` functions, you can also find them both here:

1. `JSON.parse()` [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)
2. `JSON.stringify()` [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

```js
// vanilla js version of $(document).ready(function(){/*code here*/});
window.ready = function(fnc) {
  if (typeof fnc != "function") {
    return console.error("You need to pass a function as a param.");
  }

  try { // try time out for some old IE bugs
    setTimeout(function () {
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", fnc());
    }, 10)
  } catch (e) {
    try { // sometimes timeout won't work
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", fnc());
    } catch (ex) {
      console.log(ex);
    }
  }
};

// shorter than $(document).ready();
ready(function() {
  var object = {
      name: "Jack",
      age: 30,
      location: "U.S.A.",
      get_pay: function() {
        console.log("test");
      }
    },
    test;

  console.log(object);

  var obj_string = JSON.stringify(object);

  // run a test
  var run_test = function() {
    // output the stored object 
    test = localStorage.getItem("test");
    console.log(test);

    // to make js turn it into an object again 
    test = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("test"));
    console.log(test);
  };


  // demo of trying to store an actual object
  try {
    localStorage.setItem("test", object);
    run_test();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }

  // demo of trying to store the string
  try {
    localStorage.setItem("test", obj_string);
    run_test();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
});
```

Comment: I have tried using the stringify thing, but one more time, just like on the comments above, I don't have a problem with the "<script>" section of the html file. I don't know how to call the saved variable value when the page loads, in the "<body>" section.

Comment: Okay, so firstly I've added a function to ensure the dom has been loaded(`ready`). So this will run once everything has loaded within the dom **excluding the likes of images**.  So all you need is the `ready` function?

Comment: @StefanKostoski it's just occurred to me, **why** have you included a script to have `jQuery` and you're not really using it at all? That just seems a little odd to me.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that, I forgot to remove it. It was there when I tried using the jQuery for my desired task.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/45115/

here we are using `Cookie` concept and  `jquery.cookie.js` to accomplish what you are trying to do.

to properly check the fiddle you need to press "Run" every time, you can open the same fiddle in 2 tabs write something in the first fiddle then just press run in the 2nd fiddle tab the value should automatically update, here the 
`$(function(){});`  replicates your pageload

Comment: This relies completely on `jQuery` though? This solution also doesn't fully answer his question as he did specifically ask about `localStorage`. I mean there's nothing wrong with your solution, nothing at all, if anything if you want to support super old browsers then this is a better solution than my own. Plus if you wanted to go the cookie route, I don't see why you wouldn't just use vanilla JS, save relying on `jQuery` ... It's just more lightweight that way... Only reason I chose to stay away from `jQuery`, it's pretty bloated tbf, but it's meant to be at the same time, so....

Comment: Yeah I completely agree with you, but with Jquery the code looks much cleaner and elegant, it saves effort to write vanilla JS and yes it is exactly how you anticipated it, it's written to support old browsers and will work on multiple platforms  as well.

Comment: And as he has mentioned in his  question that he is **Searching** for options to keep value intact even after page load.

so this might be one of the alternatives too, and thanks a lot !! for your answer as well I have learnt something new from it  :)

Comment: No need to thank me and touché, but personally I refuse to even bother trying to support anything older than IE9, I know IE9 actually **works** with `localStorage` as I've used it in a commercial project. As for `jQuery` being neater, that's debatable, but it does sure as hell save you writing your own features, but personally I find that part fun! ;) .... To be fair, I'm not hating on `jQuery`, it's a very good one-fits-all solution, but I then argue that it's not actually great at one specific thing, because to be fair, that's not what it's made for! :)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I don't ask specifically to use "localStorage", i just found that that is most commonly used to save data even if the browser is closed. But the thing is, just like on all answers I found on the internet: I don't have a problem with the "<script>" section. I just don't know how to call the saved variable value when the page loads, in the "<body>" section.

Just like on the comment above and bellow. 

But still, thank you.

Comment: in the page load section you can directly consume `var text = $.cookie("example");`  as mentioned in my JSFiddle

Comment: Please post the actual answer here using the `[<>]` too. I know it does not handle localStorage, but jsfiddle links grow stale - for example they use https now

Answer (score 0):

My question isn't exactly answered, but I completely avoided storing info on a device. Now I'm just reading the value straight from the arduino and it works. But thanks to everyone that provided some help.